# How to divide the result of calculation on groups?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Good day! Could you help me with query?

I have a table "payments":

```
payments
user_id     amount     payment_time    sale_type
1           20          31.01.2011      card
1           10          02.01.2012      cash
3           10          03.01.2012      card
4           15          05.02.2012      cash
...and so on
```

The task is to select total amount of payments for 01.01.2012 - 30.01.2012 and divide this sum on groups due to the amount user ever payed.

The groups are "0-10" - if sum is 0 -10 $
                "10 and more" - if sum > 10 $.

My code:

```
SELECT * from (select IFnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason, total_amount 
FROM 
    (SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total_amount, CASE
        when amount<=10 then '0-10'
        when amount>10 then '10 and more' END AS diapason
           FROM (SELECT distinct payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
                FROM payments inner JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
                     FROM payments where payment_time between '2012-01-01' 
                     and '2012-01-30') a ON payments.user_id = a.user_id 
          GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t  GROUP BY diapason WITH ROLLUP) as 
 t1  ORDER BY total_amount desc;
```

What is wrong here?

Expected output

```
diapason     total_amount
0-10              10     - here is user with id 3 
10 and more       10     - here is user with id 1 (because he ever payed 30)
total
```

Comment: Don't you think your total_amount column in expected output needs to be reviewed. Why it is 10 in every case?

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai , no it's alright. Because I select from 01.01.12 until 31.01.12

Comment: Then for 2nd row it should be 30.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai , No 20 was in last year.

Comment: Ohhh. Got it. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai, are any proposals how to decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
select case when p2.amount <=10 then '0-10'
        else '10 and more' end diapason
      ,p1.amount "total amount"
      ,p1.payment_by_card
      ,p1.cash
from (select user_id, sum(amount) amount, payment_by_card, cash
      from payments
      where payment_time between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-30'
      group by user_id, payment_by_card, cash) p1
join (select user_id, sum(amount) amount
      from payments
      group by user_id) p2
on p1.user_id = p2.user_id
```

Here is the fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22caaa/8

Comment: thank U for your help!
Can U say what to do if I need to add here a few columns ("payment_by_card" and ""cash')? There are such culumns in table "payments".
So, the result must include 4 columns (those and new ones)

Comment: Add those columns in both the inner queries.

Comment: can U write an axample?